# Font Support Online M

Tags: discussion, feature-request, formatting

It's kinda of tricky to get the following equation into the stackexchange site but is there a way to support the Mathematica font(or some equivalent) online?

For example the Integrate symbol doesn't display on this site but it is supported by the Mathematica editor.

```
∫y[x]x
```

Can we use [these fonts](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/10427) online legally even?

**EDIT:** Although the questions are similar, one question is about Unicode, while mine is about font issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site)

Comment: @Karsten7. I believe this is a font issue please explain if it is not.

Comment: [DifferentialD not displayed correctly](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1553/1063) is a related question, although not a replacement for this one.  Many legitimate Mathematica symbols are lost in translation to StackExchange.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes and [these fonts](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/10427) should fix everything, although I have not yet tried them.

Comment: It looks like it is possible ([example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93376/209088)) to have a different fonts than other subsites. I think this indeed a font issue, indeed fonts can display characters in the [private use areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas). I think this question is close enough to the linked one to be considered a duplicate (considering the addendum there). I hope we can make this work and thanks for asking this.

Comment: Just having the fonts isn't particularly useful without the proper typesetting. Also copypaste into *Mathematica* should be fully supported to be more helpful than the MathJaX equations.